# Python Split on Space Except Between Words & After Commas

Tags: python, regex, split, whitespace

I would like to split the following

```
11/27/2019 Sold $900,000 -6.2% Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey

11/2/2019 Pending sale $959,000
```

into

```
['11/27/2019', 'Sold', '$900,000', '-6.2%', 'Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey']
['11/2/2019', 'Pending sale', '$959,000']
```

I've tried with regex, but not had any luck figuring out how to do a `re.split()` combination that can accomplish the splitting except between words and after commas.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex, which looks for a space which is not preceded by a letter or comma, or is not followed by a letter:

```
(?<![a-z,]) | (?![a-z])
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/piQSID/4)

In python:

```
import re
a = "11/27/2019 Sold $900,000 -6.2% Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey"
b = "11/2/2019 Pending sale $959,000"

print(re.split(r'(?<![a-z,]) | (?![a-z])', a, 0, re.IGNORECASE))
print(re.split(r'(?<![a-z,]) | (?![a-z])', b, 0, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output:

```
['11/27/2019', 'Sold', '$900,000', '-6.2%', 'Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey']
['11/2/2019', 'Pending sale', '$959,000']
```

Comment: Okay thanks, that works! I was trying to use the lookbehinds to do it, but couldn't quite figure out how to format them. That makes sense now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your data from? Is it from a CSV? Can you change the separators into commas or something else?

Right now you can only use spaces for your separator.

E.g.:

```
>>> x = '11/27/2019 Sold $900,000 -6.2% Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey'
>>> x.split(" ")
['11/27/2019', 'Sold', '$900,000', '-6.2%', 'Suzanne', 'Freeze-Manning,', 'Kevin
', 'Garvey']
```

Notice that it chops up the string 'Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey'

If you had tabs as your separators, you could easily do something like this:

E.g.:

```
>>> x = '11/27/2019\tSold\t$900,000\t-6.2%\tSuzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey'
>>> print(x)
11/27/2019  Sold    $900,000    -6.2%   Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey
>>> x.split("\t")
['11/27/2019', 'Sold', '$900,000', '-6.2%', 'Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey']
```

Optionally, if you will always have 5 columns of data, such as your first string, you could tell it to stop splicing after the fourth iteration.

E.g.:

```
>>> x.split(" ",4)
['11/27/2019', 'Sold', '$900,000', '-6.2%', 'Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey']
```

See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split for more details about the separators.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import re
l = '11/27/2019 Sold $900,000 -6.2% Suzanne Freeze-Manning, Kevin Garvey'

l = l.replace(" ", '&')  # replace the & for a character that you are ensure that won't be in you string

l = l.replace(',&', ', ') # This ensures the maintence of the "after comma words"

result = re.sub(r'([^0-9, %])&([^0-9, $])', r'\1 \2', l) # Now every white space is a & char, you know that it must be splited if the previous item is a number (price in this case) a percentage symbol, the next word should be the $ (also indicating the price), or a number. If the pattern does't follow this rules, it is considered a word that won't be splited. Note, the code replace just the & ('after words' and 'after commas) for ' ' and keep the rest of the regex pattern intact. 

result = result.split('&') # Now just the itens that must be splited has the & between them. 

print(result)
```